# Confusion about C Major Chord on guitar

Tags: guitar, chords, scales

I was reading the article about  major scales here -> https://www.lotusmusic.com/lm_chordnames.html and was trying to look at the C Major chord on my guitar.

In the article it says that the triad consists of C E and G. But when I am looking at how i play a C chord on the guitar i am pressing C(B first fret) E(D second fret) and C(A third fret).

[image]

**This confuses me? Where is the G and why do I play a second C?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The G is on the third string open. Sometimes open strings will give one of the notes needed for a chord.

There are other ways to play a C major chord at that position (open). As well as the three fingers used, bottom string 3rd fret can play another G, making a second inversion. Or - it can be played open (it's another chord tone - E), along with the rest. Or, press top (thin) string on 3rd fret, for yet another G note. Since there's an E played on 4th string, it doesn't matter that the top E has been replaced by a G. So many options...

You play a second C *because you can*. You don't *have* to, but on guitar, playing a triad on an instrument that can make six different notes at the same time, it's often the way chords, especially triads, get played. Some chords will have three of the same note names in different octaves. Nothing wrong there.

Comment: Ahh oke thanks. And that means that a triad on a guitar only means that it has max 3 DIFFERENT notes, and sometimes more of the same? :D But why should in C major the top E be muted, is not E allowed then?

Comment: You're not reading it right. Where there's 'X' over a string, don't play it, or mute it, ( although here, that open bottom works fine), and where there's 'O' play *that* string open so no need to put a finger on it, mute it, or worse still, catch it with another finger.

Comment: Yeah i know that i have to mute the bottom E in the chord but i was wondering why because it is also an E and i thought E's are allowed in the C major chord :)

Comment: Good thinking! Yes, it can be played open with the rest of the C chord. It's just that some sites only advocate playing root versions of chords, but also, the second inversion, when that bottom E is open, can sound less decisive. Having said that, it works well in some songs.

Comment: I'll add that usually the lowest and highest notes are heard more, than notes in the middle of a chord. For example, if you play E on 1st or 6th string, it will be more 'decisive' to our ears in terms of chord sound. You can very well illustrate it playing any 7th chord with 7th on top / bottom (e.g., Cmaj7 as CEGB compared to BCEG)

Comment: Regarding the low E. Inverted chords in low ranges can sound muddy. The open guitar chords are fairly low range and so normally the lower, non-root tones are omitted. *Also* traditional voice leading will have the 3rd of a 1st inversion chord move up by step to the root of the next chord. Open guitar chords are not usually used in that way. One notable exception from rock: Highway To Hell the D is in 1st inversion with a low F# which moves up by step to the root of following G chord.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - so going from C or C7 to F sounds like a likely place to use the first inversion.

Comment: @Tim, I was thinking the same, although that open C a full step lower that D/F# can get pretty muddy.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - tone control and playing technique go a long way to obviate that.